# command line shutdown without uac prompt

Tags: windows, uac

******** Sorry, false alarm, thanks for your time user9811991 - but it was a setting in my program that was checked that should not have been.   **********

I'm trying to help out a person with disabilities by setting their PC (Win 10) to automatically restart based on a verbal command to a google home - with their PC also running a freeware program I wrote which works to accommodate that.

In short the program I wrote just runs a shell command over the windows shutdown command - more specifically it runs:
shutdown /r /t 10 /c "requested by home automation"

On my system this works fine, and the restart just happens.  On their system, they get a UAC prompt (which I don't get) which due to their disability causes issues.

I've connected into their PC, but when the shutdown command gets issued my remote connection goes blank, and I am not seeing what they are seeing.  But it sounds as if it is the UAC prompt.

I've had them check their UAC setting, and it is set to the default as is mine.

They are using Windows Defender and I am not (I'm using Bit defender).

Any suggestions would be appreciated on how to not have the UAC prompt appear on their system (as is the case on my system) would be appreciated - however, I don't want to ask them to lower their UAC settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have never gotten a UAC prompt for command line shutdown before, but here are a couple things you can try. If you distributed your script to them over the internet, make sure the script is unblocked. You can do this by right-clicking the script file, clicking `Properties` then checking `Unblock` and then clicking `OK`.

Another thing you could try (altough this is unlikely to help) is connecting the script to a shortcut, and pointing your automation program to run the shortcut to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, false alarm, thanks for your time user9811991 - but it was a setting in my program that was checked that should not have been.

Comment: Can you tell us *what* setting was enabled? Without knowing that, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: they had checked an option to run the program with admin privileges, however that option should have been left unchecked.

Comment: Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.