# How to shutdown/restart from the command line without elevation?

Tags: windows, command-line, shutdown, uac

Has something changed in Server 2019?

Under Server 2016 I was able to run this command in a non-elevated prompt:

```
shutdown /r /t 0
```

In Server 2019, however, when I attempt to do so I get:

> Access is denied.(5)

The command works fine from an elevated prompt. I'm signed in as the same domain admin that I was under Server 2016 (same SID, same domain).

[This Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/1412867) asks a similar question, but the answer is proprietary.

Articles like this are readily available:

http://woshub.com/allow-prevent-non-admin-users-reboot-shutdown-windows/

...but I don't want to allow a non-admin user to run the commands. I'm the domain admin and I want that supreme power all to my itty-bitty self. I just don't want to have to wrangle with UAC in order to exercise it.

Under Server 2019, how can I successfully run this command from a non-elevated prompt as I did in Server 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Server 2016 by default had the following privileges for an
Administrator:

- Shut down the system
- Remove computer from docking station
- Change the time zone

But Server 2019 broke some of these permissions. To fix:

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to
  *Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assessments*
- For each of the above listed privileges, ensure that your user
  account, or Administrators, is included. (A subset of these permissions
  might be enough.)
- Do `gpupdate /force`
- Logoff and log back on, you should now be able to shutdown and restart.

You could also go the whole route and disable administrators
being bothered with UAC.

This policy is named
"Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode" and is found at
*Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings >
Local Policies > Security Options > User Account Control*.
Change the default of "Enabled" to "Disabled".

Comment: Hm, that's strange... the local `Administrators` group is already present in all three of those. `Administrators`, of course, includes the domain admin.

Comment: It might be worth noting that I'm able to run `shutdown /l` without elevation. Maybe something changed within the executable.

Comment: I disabled UAC for administrators, as you suggested, and it accomplishes my goal, but it leaves me with a nervous, unsettled feeling in my belly. It strikes me as throwing the baby out with the bath water. Maybe it's just my imagination.

Comment: Now isn't that something! I added the domain admin directly to the `Shut down the system` permission, and it worked. I guess it doesn't spelunk the groups. Go figure.